# client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, httpd.conf, bitnami

I have word-press website on ec2 with bitnami image in error log file i am getting bellow snippet error.

I have overwrite default `htaccess.conf` file with my `.htaccess` file

now the the path for `.htaccess` file is `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/`

```
client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/
client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/robots.txt
localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -D DISABLE_BANNER'
client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/easy_team_manager/index.php, referer: http://www.example.com/team/
```

You can see bellow my conf file structure.

httpd-vhosts.conf file snippet

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomainname.com
    ServerAlias mydomainname.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomainname.com
    ServerAlias mydomainname.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.key"
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd-app.conf file snippet

```
<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
    <Proxy "unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/wordpress.sock|fcgi://wordpress-fpm" timeout=300>
    </Proxy>
</IfDefine>
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
    Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    <IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
       <FilesMatch \.php$>
         SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://wordpress-fpm/"
       </FilesMatch>
    </IfDefine> 
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
        Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/banner.conf"
</Directory>
#Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf"
```

banner.conf file snippet

```
# Banner configuration
<IfDefine !DISABLE_BANNER>
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m!^/+(index\.php)?/*$!i" >
       SetEnv  "DISABLE_BANNER" "YES"
    </If>
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/bitnami/banner/conf/banner-substitutions.conf"
</IfDefine>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably trying to connect to your local setup over SSL because the error log says

> **localhost:443**:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

But, your SSL certificate file

> **SSLCertificateFile** "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.crt"

has probably been created authenticating `example.com` only. So, while this SSL setup probably works online, it would fail when accessed over `localhost` because the browser knows that the local server isn't `example.com`.

To workaround this problem, you  can override a DNS lookup request for `example.com` by mapping it to `localhost` in your `/etc/hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
127.0.0.1    www.example.com
```

This allows you to connect to your local setup while still making your browser believe it's on `example.com` when clearly it's not. The SSL handshake should succeed now as the browser would't reject the server certificate this time.

Comment: you mean that host file i have to set 127.0.0.1  mydomainname.com from 127.0.0.1  localhost ??

Comment: i have done changes i have replaced 127.0.0.1 localhost with 127.0.0.1  mydomainname.com before that i have delete the error log file and seems that the file is of error log i snot created i hope is this working but need to be observe after every hour to confirm is that working or not?

Comment: There's no need to remove the localhost entry. Add it back again or it may interfere with any other network software running on that machine. You just need to add these new mappings to the file. It's fine if more than one domains point to the same address.

Comment: now i have added as you say  127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 mydomainname.org
127.0.0.1 www.mydomainname.org but it's showing error again in error log:-localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: and also getting this error again :- client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/my-food-diary

Comment: What url are you using to access your local website?

Comment: Try putting localhost at last. Since, the logs are saying localhost again inspite of you using domain.org it seems like a reverse dns lookup is happening for the host name.

Comment: i have try this also but still not success

Comment: I think it worked before when you had no localhost there. So, remove or comment it out with `#` before that entry. You can easily enable the entry by just deleting the `#` if and when you feel like running some other network software that needs it to work properly.

Comment: This probably is your only option because if you could make a certificate work on just about any other site including `localhost` that would kind of defeat a certificate's own purpose which is to verify the authenticity of a web server.

Comment: To add #localhost is not make any technicaly sense so i can't use this option

Comment: that also not working as i say you #locahost works for me but that time i am forget to restart app ache so that error log file was non jun rated  can you please mail me your email if on bcsplsanjay@gmail.com so that can i send you the configuration file structure.once you sent update the comment.